# How can I put text on slider images?

Tags: css, wordpress

Please check the link http://gtmhospitality.biz/

I want text "From Big Cities" on the slider images.

Thanks,

Comment: You should ask question specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

this CSS may solve your problem.

```
.slider_full h1 { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999; background: transparent; }
```